# Linked spreadsheet data to document

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have created a Google document that links to tables in a Google spreadsheet.

Now I want to copy both the spreadsheet and the document.

However, the link remains to the original spreadsheet.

Where can I set the filename of the copy of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

- in the spreadsheet, you need to look for import formulas like **`=IMPORTRANGE()`** where you need to change URL or ID
  [image]

- in the document, you need to look for link menu appearing on the top right of your imported table and by selecting **change range** you can change the source
  [image]